# cannot install pygame in anaconda 3 (python 3), linux

Tags: python, linux, pygame, anaconda

When trying to install pygame in anaconda 3 (python 3), linux, I have

```
conda install -c CogSci pygame=1.9.2a0
```

Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pygame=1.9.2a0
  - singledispatch
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What should I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

That is an unusual error since conda can normally ask for a version change of a package to ensure the environment works together.

A good bet would be to create a new environment specifically for coding with PyGame.

```
conda create -n games python pygame
```

Then activate your environment using

```
activate games
```

To code and use the pygame package.